# Correct bash syntax for path with space and comma

Tags: bash, rsync

I am using rsync to backup data. Now I have troubles backing up a folder that contains a comma and a space character. I use an array with source names:

```
dirs=(
    /home/user/Desktop
    ...
    /home/user/foo, bar
)
```

What is the correct syntax for the last entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just quote them:

```
dirs=(
    '/home/user/Desktop'
    ...
    '/home/user/foo, bar'
)
```

This prevents [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) from occurring. As these are string literals (no expansion of variables, for example), I prefer to use single quotes.

Presumably you plan on looping through these directories, in which case, you should also quote the variable inside the loop:

```
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    rsync command using "$dir"
done
```

Double quotes are needed here so that word splitting isn't performed but the variable is still expanded.